# Is RequireJS loading files asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

> Note: requirejs([], function() {}) will call the function callback asynchronously in RequireJS 2.1+ (for earlier versions it was synchronously called). However, when running in Node, module loading will be loaded using sync IO calls, and loader plugins should resolve calls to their load method synchronously. This allows sync uses of the requirejs module in node to work via requirejs('stringValue') calls:

What does this mean? Does it mean requirejs in node is not truly asynchronously loading files? Because it's using sync IO calls?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the quote says?

Comment: afaik: node's `require` and RequireJS's `require` have nothing in common, two total different worlds. Just the same word used to define a loading function

Comment: I'm a bit confused, if it's synchronously loading anyway, why not just use requirejs('foo')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That quote is telling you:

1. When RequireJS runs in Node, it can load modules in a truly synchronous way when called as `requirejs(module_name)`. **Note that this has no equivalent when RequireJS runs in a browser.** Yes, you can do `requirejs(module_name)` on the browser side but this will only work without error if the module has *already* been loaded and this loading happens asynchronously. It is not truly synchronous. The same kind of call done through RequireJS when it runs in Node, however, is truly synchronous.
2. However, when you call it by passing a list of dependencies and a callback, the callback will be called asynchronously. A call of the form `requirejs([], function() {})` is asynchronous both in the browser and in Node.

In a comment you ask:

> I'm a bit confused, if it's synchronously loading anyway, why not just use `requirejs('foo')`?

If this call is meant to run only in Node, then you don't have to bother with using the asynchronous form of the call. However, if you write code that is supposed to run in Node, **and** in the browser you have to be careful about how you use such call. For instance a `main.js` file that does:

```
requirejs.config({...})
var foo = requirejs('foo');
foo.whatever();
```

will at best fail intermittently in a browser. At least once in a while, it will raise the ["module not yet loaded for context" error](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded). If you want the code to run without error, you have to do:

```
requirejs.config({...})
requirejs('foo', function (foo) {
    foo.whatever(); 
});
```